# PyQt: Displaying QTextEdits over the window

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to display some QTextEdits over my main window at arbitrary locations.  Below is my first attempt.  It doesn't quite work.  If I create the text edits before I show the window, the text edits appear, but if I create them after I have shown the window they don't appear.  What's up with that?  How can I get the ones created later to show up?

```
import sys, random

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.resize(500,500)

def new_text():
    print "new text"
    text = QtGui.QTextEdit(win)
    text.move(random.random() * 400, random.random() * 400)

for i in range(3):
    new_text()

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.connect(timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), new_text)
timer.start(500)

win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I got it.  You have to call show on each widget before it appears.  I guess QMainWindow.show recursively calls the method for all of its children.  So just add text.show() to the end of the new_text function and it works.